# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 in json_encode from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, d3.js

i am trying to use the index.php file in d3 based on form input..

index.html

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <body>
            <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            var links; 
            d3.json("index.php", function(error, json) {
              links = json;
            try{ 
              JSON.parse(json) 
            } catch(e) { 
              document.writeln("Caught: " + e.message)
            }
            });
            </script>
```

that shows

```
        Caught: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

( the index.php file return Undefined.)

index.php

```
             <?php
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            if(isset($_GET['input']))
            {
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin321","php");       

            if (mysqli_connect_errno())                
              {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }
            $name=$_GET['input'];
             $sql="SELECT * FROM newtab where value LIKE '%".$name."%'";
             if(!$sql){
                 echo"error".mysqli_error();
            }

            $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                    $data = array();
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
                     $data[] = $row;
                     }  
                     function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0,
                   $tree = array())
            {
                foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
                {
                    if($row['parent'] == $parent_id)
                    {
                        foreach($row as $k => $v)
                            $tree[$row['id']][$k] = $v;
                        unset($src_arr[$idx]);
                        $tree[$row['id']]['children'] 
           = buildtree($src_arr, $row['id']);
                    }
                }
                ksort($tree);
                return $tree;
            }

            function insertIntoNestedArray(&$array, $searchItem){

                if($searchItem['parent'] == 0){
                    array_push($array, $searchItem);
                    return;
                }
                if(empty($array)){ return; }
             array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key, $searchItem){
                if($item['id'] == $searchItem['parent']){
                        array_push($item['children'], $searchItem);
                        return;
                    }
                    insertIntoNestedArray($item['children'], $searchItem);
            }, $searchItem);
            }
          $nestedArray = array();
            foreach($data as $itemData){
             $nestedArrayItem['value'] = $itemData['value'];
                $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
                $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];

                $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
                $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();

                insertIntoNestedArray($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
            }
            header('Content-Type: application/json');

                 $json= json_encode($nestedArray);
             echo $json;

            }

            ?>
```

index.php return [json](http://pastebin.com/ex3UJng8)which is valid...(validate thro jslint)

but what will be the reason for this error??

draw.html

```
                    <html>
            <head>
            <title> draw</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
            <form name="vinform"method="get"action="index.html">
            <input type="text" name="input"id="data">
            <input type="submit" value="Show" id="display">
            </form>
            <div id="content">
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

update 1

```
        try{ 
              alert(json) ;
            } catch(e) { 
              document.writeln("Caught: " + e.message)
            }
```

without JSON.parse output is [here with empty console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jCZT.png)

update 2 : Based on  Gerardo Furtado to remove the d3 ,i used with ajax in index.html file

```
                  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                success:function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });             
        });
            </script>
```

in returns the json correctly as i posted in the pastbin..but i want to get the value for d3

update 3

```
             <script>
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#vinform').serialize(),
             }).responseText;
           var data=jsonData;
            document.write(data);
            </script>
```

shows UNDEFINED

Comment: If you do simply this: `d3.json("index.php", function(json){ console.log(json); })` what do you get in the console?

Comment: maybe you DON'T need to parse it?

Comment: console is empty ..

Comment: if your console is empty then there's clearly a return problem. so solve that first

Comment: plz see my update..

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado  d3.json("index.php", function(json){ console.log(json); })  shows null

Comment: I didn't say to remove the `d3.json` function, but to remove the D3 tag *from the question*, and add a PHP tag to the question (which I see you just did).

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding ...php added already